# I use rxjava2+retrofit2+okhttp3 in my android application and get crashed when app not connected to internet

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, okhttp

I've find some solution ([OnErrorNotImplementedException when Interceptor throws.](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2415)), but I still get `OnErrorNotImplementedException` and `SocketTimeoutException` and the app crashes.

My code to handle HTTP result:

```
observable.compose(TransformerHelper.<Response<T>>io_main()).doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
        requestCallback.onBefore();
    }
}).doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
        requestCallback.onAfter();
        requestCallback.onError(throwable);
    }
}).doOnComplete(new Action() {
    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        requestCallback.onAfter();
    }
}).onErrorReturn(new Function<Throwable, Response<T>>() {
    @Override
    public Response<T> apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}).subscribe(new Consumer<Response<T>>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Response<T> response) throws Exception {
        try {
            requestCallback.onAfter();
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                requestCallback.onSuccess(response.data, response.msg);
            } else {
                requestCallback.onBizErr(response.code, response.msg);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            requestCallback.onAfter();
            requestCallback.onError(e.getCause());
        }
    }
}, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
        requestCallback.onAfter();
        requestCallback.onError(throwable);
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to increase your chances of getting an answer you should probably paste in your stack trace. Also, why are you returning null in `onErrorReturn`. `null` doesn't have an isSuccess method.

Answer (score 0):

`return null;` - In RxJava2 `null` can no longer be emitted to the stream ([What's Different in 2.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#nulls)). This means that returning `null` will just cause an NPE to be emitted instead.

To put it simply, you will either need to define a valid replacement for a failed request or define a way to deal with the exception. Otherwise it will be handled by the default exception handler which crashes the application.